# Is there a way to add to gitignore on the fly?

Tags: git, ignore

Is there a way to do this, for example?

```
git ignore file1, file2, file3
```

Comment: What's the problem with editing and committing a `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Why not implement `ignore` as an alias that simply appends the list of provided files to the `.gitignore`? Do have something else in mind?

Comment: @Phillip That's why Blagovest didn't post it as an answer to your question. I assume he was just trying to get more information about your problem so that he may, or may not, provide you with a helpful  and informed answer.  Try and post a constructive response if you want more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a small bash script which would:

- shift for each parameter

```
until [ -z "$1" ] ; do local aparam="$1" ; ... ; shift ; done
```

- call for each one: `git update-index --assume-unchanged $aparam`

And then define that script as an alias.

Comment: Thanks! So this maintains a separate 'list' of ignored files apart from what "git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore" will do?

Comment: @Philip: yes, this is purely for you local repo and won't be published (push/pull): it changes the index in order to ignore any local change to the working tree content of those files.

Comment: Adding to gitignore is not same as `update-index --assume-unchanged`. Former is for ignoring untracked files, while latter is for "ignoring" modifications to tracked file